# What would cause my taps to start with low pressure and then climb?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

Some of the taps in our home have similar behaviour: When you open them, the water takes a while to come out, and then if you open them a bit more water suddenly comes out very fast.

This bugs me because you always have to open them till they frantically spew water, and then close them a bit to get the flow you want.

Another way to describe it is this: If I know the flow rate I want is achieved by doing half a turn, I can't just open the tap half way, because then the water just trickles. I have to turn the tap one full rotation, till the water gushes, and then close it by half a turn to get the right flow.

What could be causing this?

Comment: If you are on a well the lower turn on pressure setting could be two low or a pressure tank that has lost its air charge. Pressure jumps when the switch turns the pump on. I would suspect the pressure tank if this always happens but if some times you have good pressure the switch would be my target. On city water maybe a pressure regulator that is sticking.

Comment: When that happens, I disassemble the valve and change the washers.  I go to my local rather good hardware store, the one in the 100 year old building with a mezzanine and stuff in every nook and cranny, the one where Harry Potter and Hermoine wouldn't seem out of place.  Those places have *selection*.